# My Android application crashes when navigating back to my application from other applications

Tags: android

I am working on android application, My application is crashing saying this message
'Unfortunately process "iTextSharpGeneric.ITextSharp" has stopped' when i am navigating form other application to my application. iTextSharpGeneric is my projoect name.

i found this excpetion in Adnroid device logging  window:-

**"java.lang.RunttimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest..TestActivity2}.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"**

Here is the scenari i am doing. In my application

*ITextSharpGeneric--> Opening a pdf(using adobe reader)-> After Editing pdf In Adobe reader-> Selecting Share option-> Showing list of application-> I am selecting "iTextSharpGeneric" n the list of applications(to save that edited pdf details)-> "Application Crashes here"*

I tried using the save OnSaveInstanceState() and OnRestoreInstanceState() for retaining the acitivity state. But still getting the same issue.

Here is my intent filters tags in AndroidManifest.xml

```
activity android:name="com.iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2" android:label="iTextSharp"
intent-filter
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" 
action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"
category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" 
category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"       
data android:mimeType="application/pdf"             
intent-filter
activity
```

What's wrong i am doing? Let me know you valueble suggesstions.

Here is the detailed log of exception, I just selected filter option"Android Runtime" in Android Device Logging Window.

02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1884)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1875)
02-21 14:31:33.000 E/AndroidRuntime( 5614):     ... 11 more
02-21 14:31:33.010 W/ActivityManager(  169):   Force finishing activity com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2
02-21 14:31:33.520 W/ActivityManager(  169): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4163ed28 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2}
02-21 14:31:33.650 D/OpenGLRenderer( 5215): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-21 14:31:43.820 W/ActivityManager(  169): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4163ed28 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2}
02-21 14:31:46.360 I/Process ( 5614): Sending signal. PID: 5614 SIG: 9
02-21 14:31:46.380 W/InputDispatcher(  169): channel '414cb888 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1 (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-21 14:31:46.380 E/InputDispatcher(  169): channel '414cb888 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1 (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-21 14:31:46.380 W/InputDispatcher(  169): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '414cb888 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1 (server)'
02-21 14:31:46.380 I/ActivityManager(  169): Process com.iTextSharpGenericTest (pid 5614) has died.
02-21 14:31:46.380 V/TabletStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
02-21 14:31:46.380 I/WindowManager(  169): WIN DEATH: Window{414cb888 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1 paused=false}
02-21 14:31:46.390 I/WindowManager(  169): WINDOW DIED Window{414cb888 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1 paused=false}
02-21 14:31:46.630 D/AndroidRuntime( 5645):
02-21 14:31:46.630 D/AndroidRuntime( 5645): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-21 14:31:46.630 D/AndroidRuntime( 5645): CheckJNI is OFF
02-21 14:31:46.870 D/AndroidRuntime( 5645): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-21 14:31:46.880 D/AndroidRuntime( 5645): Shutting down VM
02-21 14:31:46.880 I/AndroidRuntime( 5645): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-21 14:31:46.880 I/ActivityManager(  169): Force stopping package com.iTextSharpGenericTest uid=10086
02-21 14:31:46.880 I/ActivityManager(  169):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{41291510 com.iTextSharpGenericTest/itextsharpgenerictest.Activity1}
02-21 14:31:46.890 D/dalvikvm( 5645): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 83% free 450K/2560K, paused 1ms+0ms
02-21 14:32:29.770 D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 73% free 8194K/30151K, paused 2ms

Thanks
Sreeni

Comment: can you post a detailed log?

Comment: Hi, I posted the detailed log of exception to the main query itself. Comment window is not allowing more than 600 charecters. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

"iTextSharpGenericTest..TestActivity2}"
As you can see, you are actually passing your Intentfilter for you class wrong. There are 2 dots between `iTextSharpGenericTest` and `TestActivity2`.

May be that's the case why it is not able to detect your TestActivity2 class and hence throwing that error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding to my query. But he as you said that not problem with ".." ,It's wrongly typed. java.lang.RunttimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.iTextSharpGenericTest/iTextSharpGenericTest.Activity2}.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. One importing thing is that, My application is not crashing when i press "BACK" button on device. It's just closes pdfreader application and showing up my iTextSharpGenericTest Application.

Comment: Hey Sreeni, can you link in how you are redirecting to your class from outside? maybe that way we could see some more of where it is going wrong.

Comment: Hi. I just fixed the issue.I specified the <intent-filter> tags in the activity then the issue gone. I did some thing like this in this url https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11461/unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-when-using-app-as-launcher